# Displaying data in 3 div side by side in a row

Tags: php, html

wants to display data in 3 boxes side by side, followed by 3, etc.

code:

```
  <div class="row">
 <?php 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM zlecenia';
     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<div class='zlecenia_on col-md-8'>";
           echo "<center><h1>Zlecenie: " . $row["nazwa"]. "</h1></center><br>";
      echo "<table cellpadding='2'><tbody><tr><td> Ilość znakow: " . $row["ilosc_znakow"] . "</td><td>Dead line: " . $row["dead_line"]."</td></tr></tbody></table>";
            echo "</div>";

        }
     } else {
        echo "0 results";
     }
    ?>
```

currently there is one below the other

Comment: using classes like `col-md-8` im guessing that's bootstrap, since it follows 12 column then just simply change it to 4 each

Comment: Relly, im so stupid, thanks!

Comment: Or just use `col` and the space between all cols will be evenly distributed.